# bitly JSON API returns 500, UNKNOWN_ERROR

Tags: jquery, api

```
f = $.get('https://api-ssl.bit.ly/v3/shorten/?format=json&access_token=derpderpderp&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F')
f.done(function(r){ console.log(r);});
```

Output:

```
Object
data: Array[0]
  length: 0
  __proto__: Array[0]
status_code: 500
status_txt: "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
__proto__: Object
```

What is this `UNKNOWN_ERROR`? Without any `status_txt` I have no way of knowing what went wrong. The `longUrl` is copied from their docs, so it shouldn't be a URI encoding error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use your `&login=LOGIN&apiKey=KEY` instead of `&access_token=TOKEN`. Try http://bitly.com/a/your_api_key